# Asp page tries connecting to SQL server that doesn't exist

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am receiving the following error:

Cannot attach file 'C:\Users\redact\Documents\SLDataBase.mdf' as database 'SLDB' because this file is already in use for database 'C:\USERS\redact\DOCUMENTS\SLDATABASE.MDF'

```
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\redact\\Documents\\SLDataBase.mdf;Initial Catalog=SLDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM txTable", con);
da.Fill(dt);
gridviewtxSLds.DataSource = dt;
gridviewtxSLds.DataBind();
```

However, I deleted that configuration long ago, and the code looks like this:

```
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\slDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM txTable", con);
    da.Fill(dt);
    gridviewtxSLds.DataSource = dt;
    gridviewtxSLds.DataBind();
```

I tried rebuilding the solution, I tried recreating my new database, I tried restarting VS... I can't figure out why it keeps thinking my code looks like that when it doesn't.

Edit: In fact I can delete that whole block of code and it still shows the error and says the exact same thing.

Comment: Have you modified the connectionstring in the web.config file?

Comment: You are  not running the code that you've changed. Make sure your build is actually successful. Then search for your dll name and check the date stamp of every file that is listed. Most likely your app is pointing to a different location than you think and is running an older version. You can also check the references and right click on the dll and check the properties to see the path of the file that is used in your solution/project.

Comment: So I found that old connection string in the config and I deleted it. Still doesn't work though. And it keeps telling me build successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like I found the answer. In my attempt to figure out what was wrong I had opened a backup copy of my codebehind in VS. I unknowingly kept modifying the backup copy, which is why it never threw any errors for me during build. I just opened the codebehind in my project and suddenly realized it didn't have any of the changes I was making.